# Python iterate through JSON - dict object is not callable

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary

I want to parse flight data from Aviationstack API.
For this example, I format the URL to get data from flight with departure at Marseille airport (France) with the parameter `dep_icao=LFML` (cf. documentation) :

```
# get data for flights from Marseille airport
url = 'http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=MYAPIKEY&dep_icao=LFML'
req = requests.get(url)
response = req.json()
```

This is the response (shortened)

```
{'pagination': {'limit': 100, 'offset': 0, 'count': 100, 'total': 377},
 'data': [{'flight_date': '2022-12-24',
   'flight_status': 'active',
   'departure': {'airport': 'Marseille Provence Airport',
    'timezone': 'Europe/Paris',
    'iata': 'MRS',
    'icao': 'LFML',
    'terminal': '1A',
    'gate': None,
    'delay': 10,
    'scheduled': '2022-12-24T09:00:00+00:00',
    'estimated': '2022-12-24T09:00:00+00:00',
    'actual': '2022-12-24T09:09:00+00:00',
    'estimated_runway': '2022-12-24T09:09:00+00:00',
    'actual_runway': '2022-12-24T09:09:00+00:00'},
   'arrival': {'airport': 'El Prat De Llobregat',
    'timezone': 'Europe/Madrid',
    'iata': 'BCN',
    'icao': 'LEBL',
    'terminal': '1',
    'gate': None,
    'baggage': '06',
    'delay': None,
    'scheduled': '2022-12-24T10:05:00+00:00',
    'estimated': '2022-12-24T10:05:00+00:00',
    'actual': None,
    'estimated_runway': None,
    'actual_runway': None},
   'airline': {'name': 'Qatar Airways', 'iata': 'QR', 'icao': 'QTR'},
   'flight': {'number': '3721',
    'iata': 'QR3721',
    'icao': 'QTR3721',
    'codeshared': {'airline_name': 'vueling',
     'airline_iata': 'vy',
     'airline_icao': 'vlg',
     'flight_number': '1509',
     'flight_iata': 'vy1509',
     'flight_icao': 'vlg1509'}},
   'aircraft': None,
   'live': None},
[...]
}]}
```

Then I want to iterate through this JSON response. I can get the `pagination` info right but I'm only able to get info from the first element in `data`, so I will later loop through all results.

My problem is that I would only like to get the `iata` item nested in `flight`. The way I'm trying to get it returns `'dict' object is not callable` error.

```
# iterate through JSON response
pagination_data = response.get("pagination")
flight_data = response.get("data")[0]

total_results = pagination_data.get("total")
flight = flight_data.get('flight')('iata')

pprint(f"total results : {total_results}")
pprint(f"flight : {flight}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The get method will return a dictionnary which is not function and then can not be called

It should be `flight = flight_data.get('flight').get('iata')`

Alternatives :

(but without returning None)  `flight_data.get('flight')['iata']`

(but without returning None) `flight=flight_data['flight']['iata']`